# Why does my Lambda query return an anonymous type versus Linq's strongly-typed return value?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, types, entity

Ok, bear with me... hadn't done any Linq or Lambda until a couple of days ago :)

I'm using C# and the ADO.NET Entity Framework.  I want to query my model and get back a List of objects based on a relationship.

Here's my code:

```
var query = db.Achievements.Join
 (
 db.AchievementOrganisations,
 ach => ach.AchievementId,
 ao => ao.AchievementId,
 (ach, ao) => new { Achievement = ach }
 );

var query2 = from s in db.Achievements
 join h in db.AchievementOrganisations
 on s.AchievementId equals h.AchievementId
 select s;
```

(sorry about the formatting)

My question is why does the first query, which I believe is a Lambda Expression, return an Anonymous Type:

```
{System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<<>f__AnonymousType1<MyApp.Models.Achievement>>}
```

...but the second query (a LINQ query) I get a strongly-typed value back:

```
{System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<MyApp.Models.Achievement>}
```

Why is this?

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bit is the problem in the first call:

```
(ach, ao) => new { Achievement = ach }
```

You're creating a new anonymous type with an `Achievement` property of type `Achievement`.

I suspect you just want:

```
(ach, ao) => ach
```

... although it's slightly odd to do a join and ignore the table you're joining with.

Basically, whenever you see `new { ... }` that means an anonymous type. (Not to be confused with `new[] { ... }` which builds an array with an inferred element type, or `new List<string> { ... }` etc which will build a new `List<string>` with the given contents.

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for fixing the code layout in my post - i'm guessing I should have indented each line of code separately?

Comment: And thanks, of course, for the answer.  I'd have never have guessed that so your input is much appreciated.  Is there a time and place for Lambda vs. LINQ - I'm confused when to use them.

Comment: @ben: You need to understand that query expressions and the dot notation (or whatever you want to call them) are equivalent - or rather, every query expression is equivalent to dot notation, as it's effectively translated that way, but not every dot notation query is representable as a query expression. Use whichever is more readable for the particular example.

Comment: @jon: You mentioned that it's slightly odd to join and ignore the table I'm joining to.  I'm using the join to filter the results - like you would in SQL.  Is this acceptable in EDM?

Comment: @ben: Oh it's *acceptable* - it's just not something I've personally had to do much.